# Autohotkey on a win8 tablet: three clicks for an action

Tags: windows, windows-8, script, shortcuts, autohotkey

I would love to use three clicks on my tablet to perform an action such as ^w (closing chrome windows).

I have tried with "RapidHotkey" script but to no avail. I would greatly appreciate your help.
Thank you kindly.

Comment: Ok solved. Thanks anyway.


[code]
~LButton::
if winc_presses > 0 ; SetTimer already started, so log keypress instead
{
    winc_presses += 1
    Return
}

winc_presses = 1
SetTimer, TheKey, 600
Return

TheKey:
SetTimer, TheKey, off

if winc_presses = 3 ; The key was pressed thrice   
   {
   send ^w
   }
winc_presses = 0
Return
[/code]

Comment: Can you add that as an answer below? That way it will help others looking for the same solution. Posting it *into* the question shows that this question is still open, and doesn't help future visitors trying to find the information.

Answer (score 1):

As per the OP:

```
~LButton::
if winc_presses > 0 ; SetTimer already started, so log keypress instead
{
    winc_presses += 1
    Return
}

winc_presses = 1
SetTimer, TheKey, 600
Return

TheKey:
SetTimer, TheKey, off

if winc_presses = 3 ; The key was pressed thrice   
   {
   send ^w
   }
winc_presses = 0
Return
```